# cuando python escribe en un documento txt escribe información que no necestio

Tags: python

estoy intentando persistencia con pickle

```
import pickle
fichero = file("Ejemplo.txt", "w+")
pickle.dump("ejemplo", fichero)
print fichero.readlines()[-1]
fichero.close()
```

como no cabe el resultado del script voy a dejar la foto del resultado y el archivo .txt.
como le di la orden de leer la última línea porque necesito que me lea lo último que se hizo ,pero en vez de eso me lee otra información, quisiera saber que puedo hacer o mejor que estoy haciendo mal[image: resultado y el archivo .txt]

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué te refieres con "información que no necesito"? El múdulo `pickle` es usado para serializar / deserializar objetos.

Comment: Además de lo que comenta César, ¿que quieres decir con "necesito que me lea lo último que se hizo"?, ¿a obtener el último objeto serializado? No debes leer un archivo creado por pickle como un archivo de texto normal, debes usar el método `load()` como explica César en su respuesta.

Comment: bueok gracias pues es la primera vez que intento hacer una persistencia gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta algo así para **serializar** un objeto:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> f = open('prueba.txt', 'w')
>>> objeto = [1, 'hola', False]
>>> pickle.dump(objeto, f)
>>> f.close()
```

Ten en cuenta que no puedes leer el archivo si lo abres con `'w'` (escribir datos). Tienes que cerrarlo primero o usar otra variable para abrir el archivo:

```
>>> f = open('prueba.txt')
>>> f = open('prueba.txt', 'r')
>>> f.read()
"(lp0\nI1\naS'hola'\np1\naI00\na."
```

La información que guardaste en el archivo usando `pickle.dump` está serializada, es por eso que ves ese texto raro. Si quieres recuperarla tienes que usar `dump.load` para **deserealizar** el objeto:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> f = open('prueba.txt', 'r')
>>> objeto = pickle.load(f)
>>> print objeto
[1, 'hola', False]
>>> objeto[1]
'hola'
```

Recuerda, el módulo `pickle` es usado para serializar / deserializar objetos. Si lo que quieres es simplemente escribir en un archivo no necesitas `pickle`:

```
>>> f = open('prueba.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write('Hola\n')
>>> f.write('Chau\n')
>>> f.close()
```

Y para leerlo:

```
>>> f = open('prueba.txt', 'r')
>>> lineas = f.readlines()
>>> print lineas
['Hola\n', 'Chau\n']
>>> print lineas[-1]
Chau
```